# How to import a table with references to itself into OrientDB and have it create the Edges

Tags: etl, orientdb

I'm lost as how to import a table with references to itself, and create the correct edges.

The table '**data_lists**' has the following fields:

**id,parent, title**

### Try 1:

I used the following transformers json section in my ETL file:

```
  "transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class": "data_lists"} }
   ,
   { "edge": { "class": "isParent",
                "joinFieldName": "parent",
                "lookup": "data_lists.id",
                "direction": "out"
            }
  ]
```

However, this only creates edges where the id is equal to parent. (some rows have themselves as the parent)

### Try 2:

Looking to the link documentation I tried:

```
create link isParent from data_lists.parent to data_lists.id
```

But this creates a property in the row, much like the original table reference.
On the other hand the docs say "This is not the way to create links in general"

This does not create an edge as a separate row in the isParent class

### Try 3:

Fiddling with unsafe commands I also tried:

```
insert into isParent (in,out) values (select @rid,isParent from data_lists) unsafe
```

but this fails without error message.

So, any ideas how I could accomplish this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

"transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class": "data_lists"} }
   ,
   { "edge": { "class": "isParent",
                "joinFieldName": "parent",
                "lookup": "data_lists.id",
                "direction": "out",
                "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
            }
  ]

Comment: And add this to loader : "standardElementConstraints": false

Answer (score 0):

The other answer was partially correct, because it created all nodes, but also led to duplicate records. To avoid that, I needed to use the merge instruction

For the record, here's the complete ETL instructions I used:

```
{
"config": {
  "log": "debug"
},
"extractor" : {
  "jdbc": { "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb",
    "userName": "myname",
    "userPassword": "mypass",
    "query": "select * from data_lists;" }
},
"transformers" : [
  { "merge": {
      "joinFieldName": "id",
      "lookup": "data_lists.id"
      }
  }
  ,
 { "vertex": { "class": "data_lists"} }
 ,
 { "edge": { "class": "isParent",
      "joinFieldName": "parent",
      "lookup": "data_lists.id",
      "direction": "out",
      "unresolvedLinkAction":"CREATE",
      "if": "parent is not null and parent <> id"
      }
  }
],

"loader" : {
  "orientdb": {
"classes": [{"name": "data_lists", "extends":"V"}, {"name": "isParent", "extends":"E"}],
"dbType": "graph",
"dbAutoDropIfExists": true,
"standardElementConstraints": false,
"dbURL": "plocal:../databases/mydb",
"dbAutoCreate": true,
"indexes": [{"class":"data_lists", "fields":["id:integer"], "type":"UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX" }]
  }
}
```

}